# Uploading android symbols files to crashlytics not working in mac

Tags: java, android, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to upload symbols files to crashlytics using this command on mac:

```
firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app="ANDROID_APP_ID" /Users/macbook/debuginfo/testApp/1.2.0+141
```

But i got this error:

> java.io.IOException: Breakpad symbol generation failed (exit=126), see
> STDERR
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.breakpad.BreakpadSymbolGenerator.generateSymbols(BreakpadSymbolGenerator.java:133)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools.generateNativeSymbolFiles(Buildtools.java:273)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.CommandLineHelper.executeGenerateSymbols(CommandLineHelper.java:185)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.CommandLineHelper.executeCommand(CommandLineHelper.java:118)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.CommandLineHelper.main(CommandLineHelper.java:65)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools.main(Buildtools.java:111)
>
> Error: java command failed with args:
> -jar,/Users/macbook/.cache/firebase/crashlytics/buildtools/crashlytics-buildtools-2.9.2.jar,-symbolGenerator,breakpad,-symbolFileCacheDir,/tmp/crashlytics-32c807e8-10a3-49c0-a833-0f6da19b9dc6/nativeSymbols/1-211607324153-android-5b9e71e339cdc91b0fe928/breakpad,-verbose,-generateNativeSymbols,-unstrippedLibrary,/Users/macbook/debuginfo/testApp/1.2.0+141,-clientName,firebase-cli;crashlytics-buildtools

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem it was because after i moved all my project directory from `Ubuntu` machine to my new `Mac` machine, i upgrade the dependencie of crashlytics from `2.9.2` to `2.9.4` in `android/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.4'
}
```

so i resolved the problem by deleting the `.crashlytics` directory, then i run these commands again:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get -v
flutter build apk -v --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/Users/macbook/debuginfo/testApp/1.2.0+141
firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app="ANDROID_APP_ID" /Users/macbook/debuginfo/testApp/1.2.0+141
```